# Microcloud Cannot access target

Tags: cloud-foundry

I am new to Cloud Foundary, and trying to setup a local Micro Cloud to do some development with it.  I have VM Fusion 5 under OS X 10.8.2, Micro Cloud version reports v116-20121101.000204.

For setup, I did static IP using my internal LAN's IP, but nothing was working (could not sync DNS).  I ended up changing the VMs network adapter to Bridged Networking - Autodetect, and that seemed to fix the problem.  I can ping the static IP setup for the Micro Cloud from a terminal on the host OS (or any other device on my LAN for that matter).

The problem is that vmc and the Eclipse Cloud Foundary both seem to have problems getting to my cloud domain.  Here is the error I get on command-line using 'vmc target':

```
vmc target api.xxx.cloudfoundary.me
Host is not available or is not valid: 'http://api.xxx.cloudfoundary.me'
Would you like see the response? [yN]: y
Cannot access target (getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known)
```

As I am new to this whole process, I don't really know what any of this is trying to do, so I have no idea where to even start looking.  Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 2):

What happens when you do these commands? What does your VM report as it's IP and is that the IP that resolves with an nslookup? You may need to use option 5 on the VM console to reconfigure your network.

```
jbayer-mbpro:foo jbayer$ vmc micro status
Micro Cloud Foundry VM currently in online mode
VMX Path: /Users/jbayer/dev/micro/micro.vmx
Domain: jbayermicro.cloudfoundry.me
IP Address: 192.168.129.145

jbayer-mbpro:foo jbayer$ vmc target api.jbayermicro.cloudfoundry.me
Successfully targeted to [http://api.jbayermicro.cloudfoundry.me]

jbayer-mbpro:foo jbayer$ vmc register jbayer@blah.com
Password: ********
Verify Password: ********
Creating New User: OK
Attempting login to [http://api.jbayermicro.cloudfoundry.me]
Successfully logged into [http://api.jbayermicro.cloudfoundry.me]

jbayer-mbpro:foo jbayer$ vmc info

VMware's Cloud Application Platform
For support visit http://support.cloudfoundry.com

Target:   http://api.jbayermicro.cloudfoundry.me (v0.999)
Client:   v0.3.23

User:     jbayer@blah.com
Usage:    Memory   (0B of 2.0G total)
          Services (0 of 16 total)
          Apps     (0 of 16 total)
```

Comment: Weird...I let it set for a few hours, and now its all working.  I did notice when things were not working, it reported two IP addresses, on was the static internal LAN IP I gave it, the other was an address that looked like it came from DHCP.  Now its only showing the static LAN IP.  Maybe I just need to be more patient when I start up the VM instance.